# How to prove symmetry of the following Maxwell-Bloch equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

> I have the following Maxwell-Bloch equations:
>
> $\dot{E}=-\alpha_{1} E+ k_{1}P$
>
> $\dot{P}=-\alpha_{2}P+ k_{2}ED$
>
> $\dot{D}=-\alpha_{3}(D-\lambda) -k_{3}EP$
>
> In this system $\alpha_{1,2,3}$ are coefficients for different laser classes and $k_{1,2,3}$ constants.
>    $\lambda$ is a pumping parameter
>
> How do you prove that the system has symmetry?

I assume that you have to prove that when (E, P, D) is a solution, then so is (−E, −P, D) but how do you prove this mathematically?

Thanks!

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: @Did 

Is this correct?

$\dot{E}'=-\alpha_{1} E'+ k_{1}P'= \dot{E}$
 
$\dot{P}'=-\alpha_{2}P'+ k_{2}E'D'= \dot{P}$ 

$\dot{D}'=-\alpha_{3}(D'-\lambda') -k_{3}E'P'= \dot{D}$

So when (E'=-E,P'=-P,D'=D) you get:

$\dot{E}'=+\alpha_{1} E'- k_{1}P'= \dot{-E}$
 
$\dot{P}'=+\alpha_{2}P'- k_{2}E'D'= \dot{-P}$ 

$\dot{D}'=-\alpha_{3}(D'-\lambda') +k_{3}E'P'= \dot{D}$

Comment: The comment is marred by misprints, which is unfortunate since everything revolves around change signs, but yes the idea is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $(E,P,D)$ solves the system. Then, for example, $E'=-\alpha_{1} E+ k_{1}P$ hence $(-E)'=-\alpha_{1}(-E)+ k_{1}(-P)$, that is,  $(-E,-P,D)$ also solves the first equation. It remains to show that  $(-E,-P,D)$ solves the second and third equations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Could you maybe also explain why the energy E saturates at a steady state level that is proportional to $\sqrt(\lambda-\lambda_{critical})$?

I derived a first order dynamic model of E and took the derivative of it, and looked where the derivative is equal to $0$. This did not do the trick. Am I overlooking something or do I need another approach?